# WP multisite start from existing

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have not so much experience with multisite on wp. Actually I have created another site and I have all the standard structure that wp create for posts pages and so on. I have enabled all the plugins I need there, now I wanna put all the posts, pages, products (from woocommerce), from existing site to the new one. The question is: is there any plugin that take all the existing content and export to the new site or I have to take all dumping existing tables on db?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/ & https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Answer (score 0):

You can , you need to familier with WP-CLI tool that exports and imports all the data from one site to another site with out losing any data.

Link : [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/)

First download the wp-cli.phar by this command ,

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
```

Install and get through permission , after that you need to use this command to export all the data ,

```
wp export
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/export/

Full list of commands : https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/

Export will give you bunch of xml files that you need to import in new site.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. It seems to be good this method but I have seen that db structure has tables with wp_ prefix tables wp_2 and wp_4 ... wp_4 are the tables used from my new site. If I dump all the wp_ tables then I search and replace wp_ with wp_4_ and push the queries on db... it won't work the same ?

Comment: Ok so you need to export only that tables as you need , just pass the argument like this , wp export --tables=your tables with commas.

Comment: But in your opinion, if I dump that tables with Idk phpmyadmin and I push back replacing wp_ with wp_4_ ... will it works ? Without using WP-CLI I mean

Comment: May be it will work and not work in terms of URL issues also . Try that with backup.

Comment: Yes sure, meanwhile with WP-CLI in your opinion will work for sure right ?

Comment: Yes it will sure work.. because it processes correct and accurate data.

Comment: In the end WP-cli didn't help me because it generate an xml structure different from a dump structure and it doesn't give me possibility to export tables I need. Tomorrow I will write my solution but I think that plugins suggested by brasofilo can make all the job a lot easier